# How to test JSONP,The extra parameter is "callback"

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

How do I test JSONP, i am new to this 
i have asked to use the extra parameter as "callback",
i have the url like https://192.168.2.201/admin.php?branchid=banamex
can someone help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `callback`. Here is an example using jQuery

```
function logResults(json){
   console.log(json);
}

$.ajax({
  url: "https://192.168.2.201/admin.php?branchid=banamex",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  jsonpCallback: "logResults"
```

});